# Ionic/Cordova iOS app build error for app with extension - ** ARCHIVE FAILED **

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am experiencing an issue with running and building an iOS application with App Extensions with Cordova/Ionic CLI. In order to make my application work properly, I had to add a couple of App Extensions (CallKit Directory and Intents), and I did it using XCode - added a new Target and wrote some stuff in Swift. Everything seems to be working when I make a build from Xcode, however Cordova CLI does not seem to be able to differentiate the main app form App Extension.

```
/<Path_To_The_App>/Bridging-Header.h:28:9: note: in file included from /<Path_To_The_App>/Bridging-Header.h:28:
#import "CallKit-Bridging-Header.h"
        ^
/<Path_To_The_App>/Plugins/my.custom.callkit_plugin_written_in_swift/CallKit-Bridging-Header.h:1:9: error: 'Cordova/CDV.h' file not found
#import <Cordova/CDV.h>
        ^
<unknown>:0: error: failed to import bridging header '/<Path_To_The_App>/Bridging-Header.h'


** ARCHIVE FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
        CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
        CompileSwift normal arm64 /My Call Directory Extension/CallDirectoryHandler.swift
        CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
        CompileSwift normal arm64 /My Intent Extension/IntentHandler.swift
(4 failures)
```

It seems like the script is attempting to use bridging header files from the main app while building an Extension, which is obviously written in Swift. In Xcode I set "Install Objective-C compatibility Header" to "No" for these two targets, but Cordova CLI does not care. Probably, re-writing the Extensions in Objective-C would solve the issue, but I don't have more time to experiment with a language I'm not good with.

I used to have another build issues related to the extension, which were fixed by adding some "ifs" to Cordova lib files, but hacking is never a good solution. Googling the topic results in nothing as though nobody has ever tried to add an App Extension to a Cordova app.

Now build can be made in two steps:
1) moving files from /www to /platforms/ios/www 
2) manually running the from Xcode. 
That's annoying.

Does anybody know a good way to avoid this without having to hack Cordova scripts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I spent some time learning run-command output and saw that the build process is initiated with Xcode command line tools:

```
xcodebuild -xcconfig <Path To My app>/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig -workspace "<My App Name>.xcworkspace" -scheme "<My App Name>" -configuration "Debug" -destination generic/platform=iOS -archivePath "<My App Name>.xcarchive" archive CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=<Path To My app>/platforms/ios/build/device SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=<Path To My app>/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
```

Documentation to this command says:

> -xcconfig filename
>
> Load the build settings defined in filename when building all targets.  These settings will override all other settings, including settings passed individually on the command line.

build-debug.xcconfig imports build.xcconfig which for some reason had "SWIFT_OBJC_BRIDGING_HEADER = $(PROJECT_DIR)/$(PROJECT_NAME)/Bridging-Header.h". So apparently, it overrode bridging header for all Targets despite for .xcodeproj settings.

After commenting out this line in platforms/ios/cordova/build.xcconfig the build process runs as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be that Cordova build command was using a wrong Xcode version in my case.

I'm using Swift 3 and have two Xcode installed in my computer: Xcode 7.3.1 and Xcode 8.3.3. I could build my cordova app using Xcode 8.3.3 App with no problem, but when executing command `cordova build ios` I got the same errors as you. Here are the steps I did:

1. `$ xcodebuild -version`. This step gives you the version of Xcode
   cordova is using when building. In my case it returned `Xcode 7.3.1`.
2. `$ sudo xcode-select -switch [PathToYourXcodeFolder]`. Switch to the Xcode version you would like to use.

You may want to check the current Xcode path: `$ xcode-select -print-path`.

After I switched to Xcode 8.3.3 I could run `cordova build ios` with no errors. Hope this helps those who have the same problem as me.